# Is it possible to use sql light db with phonegap application which uses web view and jquery mobile UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile, titanium-mobile

Our idea is to develop two versions of mobile app using titanium for android app and mobile website using phonegap+jquery mobile UI at the same time.

Let's say we design our web UI using jquery mobile UI and our app uses same web UI  for the app using webview component. Is it possible to access data of local sql light db in this kind of app which uses web view for rendering.

We also evaluated Titanium Studio but with Jquery Mobile drag n drop , UI development is bit faster. So idea is , keep app size as minimum using jquery mobile UI as possible and load/save data to sql light db as user uses the app.

Going by titanium for web based app development, Would it be easier than jquery mobile UI?

Can you please provide your views about this approach and solution to this problem ? We would also love to hear suggestions of experts before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an app in Titanium which loads SQLite db file and renders a view to show. I think it runs faster in Titanium comparing to PhoneGap. Titanium runs the JS file and render the view using Native objects, instead of loading the view in WebView. For that reason, Titanium version would have less memory usage and overhead.

In the other hand, Titanium and PhoneGap both are good solutions for prototyping. So, you could create you app and present it to market faster. However, for faster speed, smaller app footprint and better user interface, it would be highly recommended to rewrite the app in Native code (iOS ObjC or Android Java).